# a variable and function with same name returns an error inside a block

Tags: javascript, function, var, hoisting, redeclaration

If we declare a variable and a function with same name, it is accepting re-declaration. But when we do the same thing inside a block, it shows **re-declaration error**.
Code:

```js
var x;
function x() {}; // no error.
```

But in this case i'm getting Error.

```js
{
  var inside; // re-declaration error.
  function inside() {};
}
```

expected result should be no error.

Answer (score 5):

This is an EcmaScript 6 change. From ES6 onwards it's no longer allowed to have duplicate bindings *within a block scope*.

The [ES5 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1) does not have such a restriction but in the [ES6 spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block) the semantics have been changed:

> **13.2.1 Static Semantics: Early Errors**
>
> *Block* : { *StatementList* }
>
> - It is a Syntax Error if the LexicallyDeclaredNames of *StatementList* contains any duplicate entries.
> - It is a Syntax Error if any element of the LexicallyDeclaredNames of *StatementList* also occurs in the VarDeclaredNames of *StatementList*.

The first part is relevant - `LexicallyDeclaredNames` contains all declarations found within the code inside the block.

Presumably, this is part of a change in semantics function declarations in ES6, since now they can be block scoped:

```js
{ //block 1
  function foo() { // declared in block 1
    return 1;
  }
  console.log("block 1: foo() === 1", foo() === 1);
  
  { // block 2
    function foo() { // declared in block 2
      return 2;
    }
    console.log("block 2: foo() === 2", foo() === 2);
  }
  
  console.log("block 1: foo() === 1", foo() === 1);
}
```

This is a syntactic sugar over this equivalent ES5 code:

```js
(function() { //block 1
  var foo = function() {
    return 1;
  }
  console.log("block 1: foo() === 1", foo() === 1);
  (function() { //block 2
    var foo = function() {
      return 2;
    }
    console.log("block 2: foo() === 2", foo() === 2);
  })();
  console.log("block 1: foo() === 1", foo() === 1);
})();
```

However, this feature cannot work with duplicate names.

The same behaviour persists for any block, including other types of block statements. Here is an example:

```js
{ //block
  function foo() { return 1; }
  console.log("block: foo() === 1", foo() === 1);
  
  if (true) { // if block
    function foo() { return 2; }
    console.log("if block: foo() === 2", foo() === 2);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) { // for block
    function foo() { return 3; }
    console.log("for block: foo() === 3", foo() === 3);
  }
  
  switch ("hello world") { // case block
    default:
      function foo() { return 4; }
      console.log("case block: foo() === 4", foo() === 4);
  }
  
  console.log("block: foo() === 1", foo() === 1);
}
```

However, it should be noted that duplicate declaration of the same *type* (`var` or `function`) do not lead to an error:

```js
{
  var foo = 1;
  var foo = 2;
  
  console.log("foo ->", foo);
}

{
  function bar() { return "a"; }
  function bar() { return "b"; }
  
  console.log("bar() ->", bar());
}
```

So, it seems like they aren't treated as *different* declarations but overwriting the same lexically declared name.

Comment: *"From ES6 onwards it's no longer allowed to have duplicate bindings within a block scope."* Small nit: That gives the impression the rules *changed*, but the old rules didn't change for the old style of declaration (*VarScopedDeclaration*), as your last snippet shows. It's just that the new kind of declaration (*LexicallyScopedDeclaration*) doesn't allow duplication. So in the same block you can have multiple VarScopedDeclations for `x`, but you can't have multiple LexicallyScopedDeclarations for `x`, or a LexicallyScopedDeclaration and a VarScopedDeclation for `x`.

Answer (score 0):

While exploring this further I came across this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError

The funny thing is that my result is different than theirs for this situation:

```
    try{
        eval(`{
            var x;
            function x(){};
        }`);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e instanceof SyntaxError);
        console.log(e.message);                // "Hello"
        console.log(e.name);                   // "SyntaxError"
        console.log(e.fileName);               // "someFile.js"
        console.log(e.lineNumber);             // 10
        console.log(e.columnNumber);           // 0
        console.log(e.stack);                  // "@Scratchpad/2:11:9\n"
    }
```

Result:

```
true // instanceof SyntaxError
06:01:10.526 VM3194:22 Identifier 'x' has already been declared // e.message
06:01:10.527 VM3194:23 SyntaxError // e.name
06:01:10.527 VM3194:24 undefined   // e.filename
06:01:10.527 VM3194:25 undefined   // e.lineNumber
06:01:10.527 VM3194:26 undefined   // e.columnNumber
06:01:10.527 VM3194:27 SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared at VM3194:16 // e.stack
```

Comment: console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)); returns ["stack", "message"]. I guess that SyntaxError in my version of Chrome isn't the same...